# What does "my.firewall" mean on linux routing table?

Tags: command-line, routing

When I run the route command on shell, I get the following connections:

```
root@ct1000-1332:/opt/storage/dlogger# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 hso0   
default         my.firewall     0.0.0.0         UG    4      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I want to know the meaning of my firewall in the routing table. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my.firewall is the symbolic host name of your gateway. Use `route -n` if you would prefer just ip addresses. Example:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ns1.smythies.co 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.0.3.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

and now with the -n option:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```